# How to assign decimal value to string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm converting a formula from Crystal Reports into a Sql View.

The SQL Syntax that produced the decimal output was this:

```
     if {ACCOUNT_INFO.InstitutionIdentifier}="TPOCFBOI" then 1.10 else
     if {ACCOUNT_INFO.InstitutionIdentifier}="TPOBCB"then 0.50 else
     if {ACCOUNT_INFO.InstitutionIdentifier}="TPOCFB"then 0.75 else
     if {INSTITUTION.Region}="WMG" then .01 else
      if {vAM_CRG_LOAN_OFFICER_NAME.LoanOfficerName} ="Margaret S. Smith" 
     then .875

      What would the code look like in a Sql View to produce a decimal (3 
      places)? 





       I tried

    DECLARE 
       @LO_Individual_Comp DECIMAL(18,3),
     BEGIN
     SELECT description INTO LO_Individual_Comp
      FROM {ACCOUNT_INFO}
      WHERE InstitutionIdentifier} = "TPOCFBOI";
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1.10' || LO_Individual_Comp;
      END;

       If > Then Sql Equivalent to return a decimal (3 places)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement

```
select
   case 
     when ACCOUNT_INFO.InstitutionIdentifier ='TPOCFBOI' then 1.10 
     when ACCOUNT_INFO.InstitutionIdentifier ='TPOBCB' then 0.50 
     when ACCOUNT_INFO.InstitutionIdentifier ='TPOCFB' then 0.75
     when INSTITUTION.Region = 'WMG' then .01 
     when vAM_CRG_LOAN_OFFICER_NAME.LoanOfficerName ="Margaret S. Smith" then .875 
END as 'Decimal'
from...
```

Now you missing detail on how your tables would join.  It appears that your trying to compare data from three different tables (ACCOUNT_INFO, INSTITUTION, vAM_CRG_LOAN_OFFICER_NAME).

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the appropriate tables to "from" and applied the proper joins. Thank you very much!

Comment: @GaryClements If this answer worked for you please click to check mark next to the answer